# About approximate eigenvalue

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis

I am in trouble when read the book "D.Henry, Geometric Theory of Semiliner Parabolic Equations". The question is relate to Page 104,proof Lemma 5.1.4.

Suppose $X$ is a real Banach Space, $M$ is a continuous linear operator on $X$ with specturm radius $r>0$. In the proof, it is says that: There exist $\lambda=re^{i\theta}$ in $\sigma(M)$. $\lambda$ is an approxiamte eigenvalue, for a fixed $\delta>0$ and any integer $N$, we may choose $u,v$ in $X$, $\|u\|=1\ge \|v\|$ such that,
$$\|Re\{M^n(u+iv)-\lambda^n(u+iv)\}\|<\frac{\delta}{2}r^n,0\le n\le N.$$

I want to ask how to know $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue? Moreover, how to proof the existence of $u,v$ fulfil that inequality?

Comment: What is $\theta$? Nevertheless, have you tried to take a sequence converging to $\lambda$'s eigenvector? Like von Mises' vector iteration for finite operators?

Comment: $\theta$ is some constant. I am not sure that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, so there may does not exists an eigenvector. In fact, even in the proof, it only claim that $\lambda$ is an approximate eigenvalue.